# document.getElementById is returning null

Tags: javascript, null, return, getelementbyid

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Item one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Item two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Item three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Item four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">Item five</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The content of **vertical.js**

```
function tabber() {
    var li = document.getElementById("navcontainer");
    var as = document.getElementById('navlist');

    return;
}

window.onload = tabber();
```

When the tabber() function is executed, the function call to **document.getElementById** returns null. Why? The element **navcontainer** definitely exists. Any clues?

Comment: are they both returning null, or just navcontainer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Heh, the devil is in the detail. You are making a mistake while assigning the `onload` event.

```
window.onload = tabber();
```

will assign the *result* of `tabber()` to the `onload` property. *Tabber() is executed straight away and not onload*.

Change it to

```
window.onload = function() { tabber(); }
```

that will work.

Answer (score 7):

You're calling the tabber function incorrectly on window load.

Change it to

```
window.onload = tabber;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the fact that you're using the JS keyword 'as' as a variable is the problem. remove that first.

Comment: Since when? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: I think you're thinking of SQL.